# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source in MVC listbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, listbox

I have found plenty of posts about this, but none of them are solving my issue.  My code right now:

```
@Html.ListBox("SelectedNewsletter", Model.Newsletters)
```

and

```
public MultiSelectList Newsletters
{
    get
    {

            return new MultiSelectList(
            new[] 
            {
                // TODO: Fetch from your repository
                new { Id = 1, Name = "item 1" },
                new { Id = 2, Name = "item 2" },
                new { Id = 3, Name = "item 3" },
            },
            "Id",
            "Name"
                );

      //      return new MultiSelectList(PromoNewsletter.All, "IdString", "Display");
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, it's all hard coded now, and it still gives the same error.  I want to do a ListboxFor, but I am trying to just get a listbox to work.  I have replaced my int id with a string representation, based on advice I found elsewhere, but now I don't see what else I can do.  It just plain is not working, even with all hard coded values and not binding to a property on my ViewModel.  Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Can you paste the code where you are loading `ViewBag`/`ViewData` with your `MultiSelectList`?

Comment: It's in my model, you're looking at the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is occurring because you have a property in the **Model** or **ViewData/ViewBag** with the name `SelectedNewsletter`.

Give a different name for the `ListBox` if you can't rename that property.

**UPDATE:**

After little more experimenting I figured out that the problem is you may be setting an integer value to the `SelectedNewsletter` that is somewhere in the **ViewData/ViewBag** or **Model**.

You can set the values that has to be selected in the ListBox as a string or array of strings to the `SelectedNewsletter`.

i.e `SelectedNewsletter = "1";`

or

```
SelectedNewsletter = new[] { "1", "3" };
```

You can also use strongly typed helper to make things easy,

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedNewsletter, Model.NewsLetters);
```

Comment: OK - the reason for that is that I WANT to bind to that property.  I just set the name to try to avoid the binding and see if it still worked.

Comment: OK, I added a whole new parameter, and this has worked.  I am not sure now how I go about binding to an actual parameter, though ? That's what I started with, this was a simplified version to try to get either something that worked, or a meaningful error message.  I even set up to see where it broken inside the .NET code, but it didn't show me anything useful.

Comment: @cgraus see my updated answer to know how to set selected values to the listbox